# How do you show multiple markers in Google Maps using PHP from the database when searching?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps, mysqli

I tried making a simple search feature for looking for hospital names then it will show to the map, I used the $_POST superglobal when searching and it will look for a result into the database. The code slightly works and by slightly works it only shows one marker on the map even though it should show multiple results based on the text you enter into the textbox.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  
  $term = $_POST['term'];
  
  $query = "SELECT * from hospitals WHERE hname LIKE '%$term%' ";
  $search_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  
  if(!$search_query){
  
    die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
  
  }
  
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($search_query);
  
  if($count == 0){
  
    echo "<script>
            alert('No Result!.');
            window.location.href='Index.php';
            </script>"; 
  } else if (empty($term)){
  
    echo "<script>
            alert('Please fill up.');
            window.location.href='Index.php';
            </script>";   
  
  } else {
  $select_all_hospitals_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_hospitals_query)){
  $post_hname = $row['hname'];
  $post_address = $row['Address'];
  $post_lat = $row['lat'];
  $post_longi = $row['lng'];
  $coordinates = 'new google.maps.LatLng( '. $row['lat']. ','. $row['lng']. '),';

  }
  
  }
  
}

?>
<html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LabSeek</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="map/map.css" />
    <link href="styles/sidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- <script src="map/map.js"></script> -->
  </head>

<body>
<div id="map">

 <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
 <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      async
      
    ></script>
<script>
  
function initMap() {
var options = {
  zoom:14,
  center: { lat: 14.586225342331847, lng: 120.99824317301842 }
}

//new map
var map = new
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);


//add marker from search
  function addMarker(coords){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coords,map:map, });
  }
 addMarker({<?php echo 'lat:'. $post_lat .', lng:'. $post_longi; ?>});

}
</script>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Some of the markup is a little screwy - 2 `html` elements, scripts within `div` elements...You are also overwriting variables in the php code

Comment: Why run the same SQL query twice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following is wholly untested! The `Object Orientated` style of using `mySQLi` is considerably less verbose than the `procedural` style and alas your code is vulnerable to SQL injection due to the use of POST data directly used within the SQL statement. You should consider using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to mitigate this threat.

It appears that you could simplify the PHP code to produce some JSON data which you can consume within the Javascript code once the page has loaded. The data is returned following a POST request so presumably the form is on another page not detailed here. You could easily have the form on the same page and remove the need to use a redirection in Javascript - or even AJAX for a much cleaner effect with no page reloads/views ( which will increase the map loads recorded by Google )

The recordset is converted to JSON and this is written to the page as a Javascript variable. Once the map is loaded you iterate through this JSON data and add a new marker for each record in the results.

```
<?php
    
    $json=false;
    
    if( isset( $_POST['search'] ) ){
    
        $term='%'.$_POST['term'].'%';
        $query='SELECT * from hospitals WHERE hname LIKE ?';
        
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$term);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $res=$stmt->get_result();
        $data=$res->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
        $json=json_encode( $data );
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>LabSeek</title>

        <link rel='canonical' href='https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='map/map.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/sidebars.css' />
        <script src='https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default'></script>
        <script>
            <?php
            
                #Convert the PHP variable into Javascript variable
                printf('const json=%s;',$json ?: '[]');
                
            ?>
            function initMap() {
                var options = {
                    zoom:14,
                    center: { lat: 14.586225342331847, lng: 120.99824317301842 }
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                
                function addMarker( coords, args ){
                    // using `Object.assign` allows you to easily 
                    // add more properties when you call this function
                    let opts=Object.assign({
                        position:coords,
                        map:map             
                    },args);
                
                    return new google.maps.Marker(opts);
                }
            
                if( json && Object.keys( json ).length > 0 ){
                    Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
                        let obj=json[key];
                        let latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( obj.lat, obj.lng );
                        let args={
                            'Address':obj.Address,
                            'Name':obj.hname
                        };
                        
                        addMarker(latlng,args)
                    })
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQbnrTvBW0ML5bVlgsgMhYCqdRR04d7k0&callback=initMap'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know my code is messy cause I'm still learning from scratch and I'm experimenting on things. I am grateful for the answer because not only it worked but it is also useful for me. Thank you for the help :)